# Powershell remoting - Policy does not allow the delegation of user credentials

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, winrm

I'm new to powershell and I'm having troubles using credentials delegation. I have the following script:

```
$session = New-PSSession myserver -Authentication CredSSP -Credential DOMAIN\Administrator
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { <Some PowerShell Command> }
```

Before running it, I did the following:

1. Run `Enable-PSRemoting` on myserver.
2. Run `Enable-WSManCredSSP Server` on myserver.
3. Run `Restart-Service WinRM` on myserver.
4. Run `Enable-WSManCredSSP Client –DelegateComputer myserver` on the client.
5. Rebooted both the server and the client.

But once I run the script, I get the following error message:

```
[myserver] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. A computer policy does not allow the delegation of
 the user credentials to the target computer. Use gpedit.msc and look at the following policy: Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Credentials Delega
tion -> Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials.  Verify that it is enabled and configured with an SPN appropriate for the target computer. For example, for a target computer name "m
yserver.domain.com", the SPN can be one of the following: WSMAN/myserver.domain.com or WSMAN/*.domain.com. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionOpenFailed
```

I checked the policies as mentioned in the error message but everything seems to be fine. What else could be blocking me?

Comment: Are you listed as an Admin on your remote box?

Comment: @Blaine: User DOMAIN\Administrator that I'm trying to impersonate is an admin of the remote server. I'm also connected to the client machine using an administrative account.

Comment: Have you enabled remote scripting on your remote box: `Enable-PSRemoting`

Comment: I have. Just edited the question to mention this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally got it to work thanks to [this page](http://powertoe.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/enable-credssp-from-a-windows-7-home-client/). It provides a script that sets the required credential delegation policies by setting the appropriate registry keys directly. Once I ran that script with admin privileges, I was able to successfully establish a CredSSP connection to myserver:

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role client -DelegateComputer *.mydomain.com

$allowed = @('WSMAN/*.mydomain.com')

$key = 'hklm:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation'
if (!(Test-Path $key)) {
    md $key
}
New-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name AllowFreshCredentials -Value 1 -PropertyType Dword -Force            

$key = Join-Path $key 'AllowFreshCredentials'
if (!(Test-Path $key)) {
    md $key
}
$i = 1
$allowed |% {
    # Script does not take into account existing entries in this key
    New-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name $i -Value $_ -PropertyType String -Force
    $i++
}
```

Comment: Is this run from the client or from the server?

Comment: From the client.

Answer (score 35):

Do the following on the server:

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server
```

Do the following on the client:

```
set-item wsman:localhost\client\trustedhosts -value *

Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client –DelegateComputer *
```

Use `gpedit.msc` on the client to enable Delegating Fresh Credentials to WSMAN/*:

1. Expand `Local Computer Policy`, expand `Computer Configuration`, expand
   `Administrative Templates`, expand `System`, and then click `Credential Delegation`.
2. In the `Settings` pane, double-click `Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication`.
3. In the `Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication` dialog box, do the following:
4. Click `Enabled`.
5. In the `Options` area, click `Show`.
6. In Value, type `WSMAN/*`, and then click `OK`. Make sure that
   `Concatenate OS defaults with input above` is selected, and then
   click `OK`.

The following command now works (after a password prompt):

```
Invoke-Command { dir \\fileserver\devtools } -computer appserver01 -authentication credssp -credential domain\user
```

See [MSDN forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/544e2da5-390d-411d-a730-1fceab18334d/network-access-when-using-invokecommand-or-enterpssession?forum=winserverpowershell).

See [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/hh751273.aspx)

Comment: could you clarify "Use gpedit.msc to enable Delegating Fresh Credentials to WSMAN/*"?

Comment: Sure @Peter. I just added more instructions. I also added the TechNet reference.

Comment: Just to help others: run the steps of gpedit on the client computer.

Comment: you can also add the credentials permenantly using: cmdkey /add:"SERVER" /user:"DOMAIN\USERNAME" /pass:"PASSWORD"

Comment: This is definitely the ANSWER! Thank you so much man :)

Comment: This did not work for me on a windows server 2016, instead the answer of ChrisB did work

Comment: Great answer, I just used this to allow Windows 11 to manage Server 2022

Answer (score 11):

I had to the need to fully automate my solution, particularly the part section in the solution that has you go into the GPO editor.

1) Enable Remote PS

```
Enable-PSRemoting -force
```

2) Enable CredSSP

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server -Force
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer locahost -Force
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer $env:COMPUTERNAME -Force
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer $domain -Force
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer "*.$domain" -Force
Set-Item -Path "wsman:\localhost\service\auth\credSSP" -Value $True -Force
```

3) Enable NTLM Fresh Credentials through the Registery:

```
New-Item -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation -Name AllowFreshCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowFreshCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly -Name 1 -Value * -PropertyType String
```

Only after this was I able to launch powershell script as the local admin that was able to run in a PSSession and preform AD actions.

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $adPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$domain\Admin", $secpasswd)
$adminSession = New-PSSession -Credential $credential -Authentication Credssp;

$sb = {
  param($p1, $p2)

  whoami

  New-ADUser ....
}

Invoke-Command -Session $adminSession -Script $sb -ArgumentList $domain,$userPassword
```

Comment: Something stupid I ran into that seems obvious after the fact... That I had the script above all in 1-script that I executed in 1-go on the remote machine. Simply, this will not work. Obviously, the permissions on your first session aren't updated to reflex what you've just changed, so change settings, close your session, and start a new one to get those settings... it wasn't obvious to me at first.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding upon Akira's answer above, in gpedit.msc I had to set "Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication" rather than "Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials".

Comment: Thanks, I just fixed my answer.